# trickle does not limit the bandwidth of gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-storage, mp4, bandwidth, gsutil, trickle

I have tried to copy a `.mp4` file from my local directory to my google cloud bucket,
using:

`gsutil cp my_filefile.mp4  gs://my_bucket`

This part works as expected, but when i try to limit the bandwidth, using:

`trickle -d 10 -u 10 gsutil cp my_filefile.mp4  gs://my_bucket`

the uploading happens at the same rate, and not with 10 kb/s. I have read that `trickle` does not handle static executable files, which the .mp4 appears to be since when running `ldd my_file.mp4`, in the terminal, it returns `not a dynamic executable`.

Has anyone experienced the same issue, and if that is the case, how was the problem handled, or am i approaching this issue the wrong way?

UPDATE 1:
Turns out it does not matter what file i use. gsutil still bypasses trickle somehow. I have tested to see if trickle worked with other programs, and it performed as expected, with bandwidth control.
I have also tested `gsutil mv` and `gsutil rsync`, with the same results, as with `cp`. I have also tested the bandwidth throttling on an arm64 system, with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You should limit the number of thread and process as described in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/Throttlinggsutil). Trickle shouldn't been applied in case of multi process.

```
trickle -d 10 -u 10 gsutil -o "GSUtil:parallel_process_count=1" \
  -o "GSUtil:parallel_thread_count=1" cp my_filefile.mp4  gs://my_bucket
```

Comment: I have tried that command from the documentation, and what happens is that a file of size 88 Mb is uploaded to my bucket after approximately 1 second. As far as i understand should it not upload with 10 kb/s  when i set `-u 10`?  
In the terminal it also states:
`trickle: Could not reach trickled, working independently: No such file or directory`

Comment: That's strange. It works on my computer (Windows10 with WSL (ubuntu) installed on it), but doesn't work on Cloud Shell for example....
To remove the error, add a `-s` as option, but it's not the issue I guess...

Comment: I think i might have to get one of my colleagues to test it, to see if there is a problem with my machine. But thank you for the reply, and tip regarding the error :)

Comment: Depending on the task it might be beneficial to set the trickle values to 1/10 of what you want, and set process or thread count of gsutil to 10, especially if you're downloading a lot of small files.